# C++: Virtual functions that need to call the same code?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11

I have a base class and classes that derive from it.  The base class `Controllable` acts as an interface for an input loop, and other classes derive from it to get a spot in that loop to get events like if a key is pressed.

```
class Controllable{
public:
    virtual void setActive(bool state) { m_active = state; }
    virtual void input(Event & e) =0;
private:
    bool m_active;
};

class Button : public Controllable{
public:
    void setActive(bool state){ /*do extra work*/ m_active = state; }
    void input(Event & e) override;
};
```

Since the `Button` class deals with events from an event queue, setting it to inactive (which takes it out of the input loop) may cause it to miss important events like a key being unpressed, so it needs extra code to put it into a friendly inactive state should it ever become active again later.

**My question**, what is the best way to ensure that `setActive` always has the intended effect of switching `m_active` to the correct state, while at the same time, not requiring derived classes to define it unless they need to attach extra needed code?

Comment: You have `;` after `}` of functions, watch for them.

Comment: Mr.TAMER - fixed!  I have a pretty itchy ; finger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep the `setActive` method non-virtual and then define a separate `protected` method `activeChanged` that the child classes can override

```
class Controllable{
public:
    void setActive(bool state) { m_active = state; activeChanged(state); }
    virtual void input(Event & e) = 0;
protected: 
    virtual void activeChanged(bool newState) {}
private:
    bool m_active;
}

class Button : public Controllable{
protected:
    void activeChanged(bool newState){ /*do extra work*/ }
public:
    void input(Event & e);
};
```

With this approach you are keeping the external *public* interface separated from the internal *protected* interface intended for child classes.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't think of using a non-virtual method this way.  I've got a number of other base classes that could benefit from this sort of treatment.

Comment: `activeChanged` should be private, not protected, since the derived classes will never need to call the base class' implementation, only override it.

Comment: Minor "bug": You'll call `activeChanged()` despite its name even without a change to the state (like `m_active` evaluates to true and you call `setActive(true)` again).

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to define "pre" and "post" virtual methods:

```
class Controllable{
public:
    void setActive(bool state) {
        preSetActive(m_active, state);
        m_active = state;
        postSetActive(m_active);
    };
    virtual void input(Event & e) =0;
protected:
    virtual void preSetActive(bool oldState, bool newState) {}
    virtual void postSetActive(bool newState) {}
private:
    bool m_active;
}
```

Note that the `setActive()` method is *not* virtual in this technique.

Comment: Oh cool.  Having two functions before and after may be overkill in this one case, but I have a few other classes this would be perfect for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Basically your case is custom made for **[Template method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).**

Answer (score 1):

How about making `setActive()` non-virtual but instead adding a second virtual member (e.g. `onSetActive()`)that's called by `setActive()`?

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:
split your behaviour between 2 tasks:

```
virtual doActive(){}; //doNothing
void setActive (bool state) {
    m_active = state;
    doActive();
}
```